# Laravel Livewire: Cannot read property '$wire' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a problem with laravel livewire. I think the problem is really simple, but I can not solve it. Let me explain everything.
I have a daterangepicker (LitePicker), he works perfect, but I want when user select date range value to set this value to the property and filter data. My problem is that I can't set value to the property.
my Js Code:

```
@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function() {
    var field = document.getElementById('filter-date-range')
    var dateRange;
    var picker = new Litepicker({
        element:field,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        lang: 'de',
        singleMode: false,
        onSelect: function(start, end) {
           @this.dateRange = start
        }
    });
})

</script>
@endpush
```

`@this` directive is compiled to

```
onSelect: function(start, end) {
           window.livewire.find('').dateRange = start
        }
```

I think the problem is here, because parameter which is passed to `find` function is empty or the id of the component is missing, and I don't know how to fix it.
Now here  is the the error I received when date is selected:

```
index.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$wire' of undefined
    at Livewire.value (index.js:30)
    at e.onSelect (book_keeping:695)
    at e.r.Litepicker.setDateRange (main.js:12)
    at e.onClick (main.js:12)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:12)
```

As you can see I use `push` directive so here is the code where I load the scripts

```
@livewireScripts
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.7.3/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
@stack('scripts')
```

Also I tried with events `wire:model` and `wire:change` without success.

Comment: `window.livewire.find('')` an empty find? How can it know which component to fetch? You should probably use Alpine to retrieve data, then you can `@entangle` it between Livewire and Alpine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used like this

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function() {
        var field = document.getElementById('date-from')
        var picker = new Litepicker({
            element:field,
            lang: 'de',
            autoApply: false,
            singleMode: true,
            numberOfColumns: 1,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showWeekNumbers: true,
            format: "D MMM, YYYY",
            dropdowns: {
                minYear: 1990,
                maxYear: null,
                months: true,
                years: true,
            },

            setup: (picker) => {
                picker.on('selected', (date1, date2) => {
                    Livewire.emit('from-selected', date1)
                });
            }
        });
    })
```

than in livewire

```
protected $listeners = ['from-selected' => 'fromSelected'];

public function fromSelected($from){
    $this->from = $from;
    $this->resetPage();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example. I already found a solution to the problem, but will give you a point for the example

Comment: @PlamenPenchev could you please provide the solution you have found? or is it the same suggested by Roland?

Answer (score -1):

Try registering AlpineJS after Livewire Scripts.